# Debugging not working on particular android device

Tags: android-studio, out-of-memory, storage

On starting app with debugging on , app gives this error.

```
Error while starting native debug session: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: Unsupported device. This device cannot be debugged using the native debugger. See log file for details.
```

Nothing on logs too, this particular device is giving this issue. Other devices with debugging is working fine.

Although I am not sure if it is a memory or storage issue since these other issues are related to it.

1. My webview load html asset file gives crash.
2. Glide images are not showing
3. Shared prefs are not working too.

These are only giving problems in android 11 ver. Nokia 3.2

Comment: When posting a question it would be nice to clearly state the request - what would you like to achieve. In this case for example "How can the debugger be attached?" https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/#problem-statement

Answer (score 0):

To successfully attach a debugger try to

- use device with API level 27 or lower
- or set `<application>` attribute [android:usesCleartextTraffic](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic) to `true`.

Credit https://web.archive.org/web/20211019054559/https://flutterq.com/solved-failed-to-open-qemu-pipe-qemudnetwork-invalid-argument/